# Vertical alignment issues with CSS rotate

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I'm experiencing vertical alignment issues in CSS. I want to display content from bottom to top.

My main objectives with this:

- content width is based on parent height;
- content is aligned with the bottom of the parent;
- content is rotated counter-clockwise;

I've seen this link: [Vertical Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745914/vertical-alignment-with-css) and other on SO. Unfortunately I can't find an answer.

I made a sample fiddle which illustrates my problem: [vertical alignment fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sn4c369g/). My results are:

- element width is based on parent width;
- there is a gap when the content is rotated;

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 92%;
}
.side-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1.0);
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-content {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1.0);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="side-content">
    <span class="text-content">Vertical Alignment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, adjusted the `transform-origin` value, and added `translateY(100%)` along with the `rotate(-90deg)`.

```
.text-content {
  ...
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 92%;
}
.side-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.main-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 255, 1.0);
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.text-content {
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  font-size: 10px;
  color: rgba(255, 102, 0, 1.0);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(100%);
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="side-content">
    <span class="text-content">Vertical Alignment</span>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `width` to `auto` and `position` to `fixed`.

```
.text-content {
    ...
  width: auto;
  position:fixed;
    ...
}
```